# Strcmp pointer from integer without cast

Tags: c, character

I'm trying to compare two character and see which one is lexicographic longer and sorting by it problem is I'm not sure how to compare single character I tried doing it with strcmp like

```
struct example
{
 char code;
}
if (strcmp(i->code, j->code) < 0)
    return 1;
```

warning: passing argument 1 of âstrcmpâ makes pointer from integer without a cast

warning: passing argument 2 of âstrcmpâ makes pointer from integer without a cast

I know that strcmp is for strings, should I just malloc and make the char code into a string instead, or is there another way to compare single characters?

Comment: if(i->code < j->code)  /* if you're only comparing one character, you can just compare the character */

Comment: Do you want case to be significant?  You might want to use [`tolower()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/tolower/) or one of the related functions before comparing values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char` is an integer type.

You compare `char` objects using the relational and equality operators (`<`, `==`, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

`strcmp()` takes a **null-terminated string**, so in C a `char *`. You are passing it a single character, a `char`. This char gets automatically promoted to an `int` in the expression (this always happens with `char`'s in expressions in C) and then this `int` is attempted to change to a `char*`. Thank god this fails.

Use this instead:

```
if (i->code < j->code)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're comparing chars and not null terminated strings, do the following:

```
if (i->code < j->code)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (i->code < j->code)
    ...
```